# How to disable one annotation in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have a case where I need to disable a custom validator annotation based on a conditional. Is this possible in springboot?

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckIdValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CheckId {
    String message() default "bad data";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: can you modify CheckIdValidator? just put the conditional there

Comment: but I need to load the property dynamically from a property file. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: sure, a validator is just a java class

Comment: You cannot disable an annotation, you could put logic in the `CheckIdValidator` that decides if it needs to validate or not. Spring Boot will be of no help here, as this is all javax.validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the @Conditional annotation or conditionalonproperty annotation